# How to include this js in a correct way

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm working with a JavaScript document that should be used in almost the entire project

It has function like this

```
$('.decimal').each(function () {

    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which != 44 || $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (event.which == 46 || event.which == 44) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (($(this).val().replace(/[^,]/g, "").length) == 0)
                $(this).val($(this).val() + ",");
        }
        var num = $(this).val().split(",");
        if (num != null && num[1].length >= 2) { e.preventDefault(); }
    });
});
```

I tryed to add it the `_Layout.cshtml` file, and that works in Views, my problem is inside the PartialViews.

In some Views, i had a PartialViews working inside modals, and in that partialviews, dont get this functions working

I can load the script again, but I'm not sure it's a good practice

What can you recommend me to load this function correctly and apply to all view and partialview?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, using `.each`, it attaches an event to every `.decimal` DOM element created at the time, but your subviews might be created after that process, so they won't be attached to those.

You might want to look into using `.on` to handle events which you attach an event handler to a parent and it will listen for any element DOM element matching the criteria, even if created after. [Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You can essentially change:

```
$('.decimal').each(function () {
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        // Handler code here...
    });
});
```

into...

```
// Selector does not have to be 'body',
// can be the highest DOM element that
// will potentially have all .decimal elements

$('body').on('keypress', '.decimal', function(e) {
  // Handler code here...
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the partial views is that these elements are loaded after you ran the code which assigned the keypress event to all of the fields. It can only add the event to elements which exist at the time.

You *could* run the code again, but you'd have to be careful to only target elements which had been added to the page later (or else you'd end up adding multiple event handlers to the existing ones) or remove all the existing handlers, and add them back in again, but now including all the new elements.

A neater way to get round it is using jQuery's "delegated event" syntax:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".decimal", function(e) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which != 44 || $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (event.which == 46 || event.which == 44) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (($(this).val().replace(/[^,]/g, "").length) == 0)
      $(this).val($(this).val() + ",");
  }
  var num = $(this).val().split(",");
  if (num != null && num[1].length >= 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

This works by placing the event handler on the `document` element, which of course already exists, and then when the event is triggered, looking for elements which the "decimal" class, and, if one of those was the root of the event, acting as if the keypress event had been attached to that event for real.

N.B. If the elements you want to handle events for have a common ancestor in the DOM which is lower down the hierarchy than `document`, you should substitute that instead, as it will be a bit more efficient.

For more details see http://api.jquery.com/on/, especially the section entitled "Direct and delegated events".

Note that your outer `.each()` loop is not required (technically it wasn't required in your original code either). This will operate on any and all elements with the "decimal" class.